# How to remove data from a cell if all other entries in the row are empty?

Tags: excel

I need to delete the value of a column if a particular column in the same row is empty

I have done the removing until now manually but it takes a lot of time

```
    AGRO ENGINEERING WORK
 Educational    19-20/4444      352254.00       27

                                352254.00
```

I need to remove the third row(column d) amongst the code if the value in column a is empty

Answer (score 1):

here is my suggestion.
try sorting the sheet on column A.
go to the first blank cell in the same column.
all the following rows have blank cells in column A.